# Auto change Password linux user every 1 hour

Tags: linux, centos, users

I want to change the password for one linux user every 1 hour. Does anyone have any ideas using bash scripts called via cron or direct command via linux cronjob?

Comment: Is this an XY problem?

Comment: It is honestly a little strange.  How would the human user know how to log into their account?  If you want to prevent anyone from logging in, then you can disable login for that user.  roaima suggests this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  I added a link to describe what that is.

Comment: What *exactly* is your goal? In other words, *why* do you want to change the password every hour? Doing so makes no real sense and your problem may be quite easily resolved without doing whatever it is you're trying to do with password changing.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @SINA GH's answer, but simplifying it for purpose of a direct answer:

If mkpasswd is available:

```
echo '0 * * * * root mkpasswd -l 50 cloud-user' >> /etc/crontab
```

If mkpasswd is unavailable:

```
echo '0 * * * * root < /dev/urandom tr -dc A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c50 | passwd --stdin cloud-user' >> /etc/crontab
```

This will put a single line in the crontab to execute automatically changing a single user's password to a randomly generated string every hour.

To break it down:

```
echo '...' >> /etc/crontab
```

adds a new line/entry to run on a schedule

```
0 * * * * root
```

runs on 0th minute of every hour on every day on every month on every weekday as root

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc A-Z-a-z-0-9
```

generates random data and filters for characters

```
| head -c50
```

takes the first 50 characters from stdin (the random characters)

```
| passwd --stdin cloud-user
```

sets the password of cloud-user to what is passed in from stdin (the first 50 random characters)

Answer (score 0):

Change user password by random string, every day.
Usage: `autopass.sh username`

#### Installation:

Save the following code in a file called `autopass.sh` in `/root/` directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
MyUser=$1
RandPass=$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12)
set +e
echo -e "$RandPass\n$RandPass\n" | passwd $MyUser &> /dev/null && echo "$(date) --> Passwd: $RandPass" >> /root/${MyUser}-pass.txt || echo "$(date) --> Error: failed to change pass" >> /root/${MyUser}-pass.txt
exit 0
```

Permission to execute: `chmod u+x autopass.sh`
Edit crontab: `crontab -e` and add this to the file: `0 3 * * * /root/autopass.sh username`
Everyday, script changes password by a random string and save it to the  `/root/username-pass.txt` file

Comment: If someone runs ps at just the right time, they could get the password from the echo command.

Comment: Only if `echo` isn't a built-in on the particular platform, @OskarSkog

Comment: Using `mkpasswd` would be safer.